# Connect to MySQL 5.1 with Python

Tags: python, mysql, linux

I have to connect to a MySQL 5.1 database.

Following Oracle indications, I tried using the 1.2 version of their python connector, but it did not seem to like python 3.10, and in effect it is not listed as compatible.

What I get is "Access denied for user...", with credentials I have triple checked. But I know this is the error you get with older auth errors.

It did say 1.2 was compatible with Python 2.7. I tried that and got super() errors, as if it were not 2.7 compatible.

I also tried PySQLdb and pymysql.

Does anybody have a 5.1 success story?

BTW, I'm on Linux so can't use the pyodbc driver.

Comment: How do you expect us to help without seeing your code??  You could have made any number of mistakes, and we have no way of knowing.

Comment: Python 2.7 is very, **very** old.  I would not recommend using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested running a Docker container of MySQL 5.1.73.

Then I ran this script with Python 3.11 and MySQL Connector/Python 8.0.32.

```
import mysql.connector
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':

    print(f"Python version: {sys.version}")
    print(f"MySQL Connector/Python version: {mysql.connector.version.VERSION}")

    config = {
            'host': '127.0.0.1',
            'port': '3307',
            'user': 'root',
            'password': 'XXXXXXXX', # obviously substitute your user and password
            'charset': 'utf8',
            'use_pure': True,
    }

    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()

    query = "SELECT VERSION()"
    mycursor.execute(query)
    print(f"MySQL version: {mycursor.fetchall()}")

    mycursor.close()
    mydb.close()
```

Output:

```
Python version: 3.11.4 (main, Jun 20 2023, 17:23:00) [Clang 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)]
MySQL Connector/Python version: (8, 0, 32, '', 1)
MySQL version: [('5.1.73',)]
```

The `port: 3307` is just what I set the host port for the Docker container.

The `charset: utf8` is important, because the current default character set, utf8mb4, was not recognized by MySQL 5.1.

The `use_pure: True` is important. If Python uses the C MySQL client, the connection fails because the modern C client has deprecated and removed old pre-5.7 password authentication. It cannot send passwords using the old protocol.

When I tried the default Python connector, this is the failure message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 288, in _open_connection
    self._cmysql.connect(**cnx_kwargs)
_mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Bad handshake
```

I took a chance that the pure Python client has not removed old password support, and that seems to be the case — at least as of 8.0.32. But I don't know when subsequent versions of the pure Python client will also remove support for the old password protocol.

I urge you to upgrade your MySQL instance. The version you are using was end-of-life by 2013-12-31, which is nearly *ten years ago* as we write this, and it certainly has numerous unfixed security vulnerabilities.

Comment: Thanks, the use_pure and charset did the trick, I'm afraid I just blindly believed what was said on the Oracle site.

Comment: I wouldn't hold this against them. The old authentication protocol is years out of date, and they are within their rights to deprecate it. You can't say it's undocumented, or a change they made without warning.

Comment: BTW, the db is not mine to replace ;-) Maybe when I have replaced the old code with my spanking new python code...

Comment: I understand, and I've been in similar situations. The client will have to take responsibility for the risk they are taking by keeping the unsupported version of MySQL. You can give them information, but you can't change their priorities.

Comment: They are not really taking a risk. The old system is running on a VM hosted W2K server, but on a closed network. The big risk for them is hardware failure. I connect via SSH over IP tunneling to a dedicated interface on Linux server that will eventually replace it. But, quite rightly, they won't be upgrading the database until all the old code has been replaced with tested and proven replacements. Interestingly, they have no plans to connect the eventual new system to the internet at large; one of the reasons they chose Linux, is it's almost impossible to have windows sans internet.